# MessageDigest SHA-512 different than openssl

Tags: java, openssl, message, digest, sha

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  I have the following code:

```
byte[] digest = new byte[0];
MessageDigest md = null;
try{
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-512" );
}
catch( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
    return digest;
}
digest = md.digest( myString.getBytes() );
```

Looking at the hex values of digest byte[] in the NetBeans debugger, it shows something different than the output of:

```
echo "myString" | openssl dgst -sha512
```

I'm guessing it's a character encoding issue, but doesn't the JVM and openssl use the default character set for the machine?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Character encodings shouldn't be an issue for `"myString"`, since that's pure ASCII. But you might want to examine the return value of `myString.getBytes()` just to make sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`echo` appends a newline at the end -

```
[steven@emu:~]% echo "myString" | hexdump -C
00000000  6d 79 53 74 72 69 6e 67  0a                       |myString.|
```

Try `echo -n`?

Comment: That was it!  You are a bash ninja!
Thank you.

Comment: That has tripped me up before too!